# Mapping ctrl-backspace in terminator

Tags: vim, terminator

I've recently started using Vim. From previous editors, I'm used to deleting a whole word by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Backspace</kbd>. After looking at the documentation I found that this was done by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>w</kbd> in Vim. The problem is that after getting used to pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>w</kbd>, I've started closing tabs and chats every time I misspell a word (while writing this question I closed this tab 5 times). So I checked how to map keys in Vim and tried this:

```
:imap <C-BS> <C-w>
```

Unfortunately, it didn't work. After a bit of research I found that the terminal does not distinguish between <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Backspace</kbd> and <kbd>Backspace</kbd>. I saw some hacks and patches to fix this issue, but I couldn't get them to work on terminator (which is the emulator I want to use).

Is there any way to map <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Backspace</kbd> in Vim when using terminator?

Comment: Welcome in Vim hell.

Comment: I like the fact that this hell is quite productive and can be improved with patches.

Comment: BTW, I'm collecting these kind of questions to hopefully be able to make a case that this particular problem is tackled in a Vim 8.0. I really want more and more uniform mapping candidates, too.

Comment: This problem can't really be fixed in vim (AFAIK). It depends on the terminal vim is running in. For a wide variety of users using vte (Gnone Terminal, Mate Terminal, Guake, etc) this problem has gotten some recent attention and might be fixed soon. See this gnome bug: https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=420039

Comment: @IngoKarkat See the above comment. ^

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Due to the way that the keyboard input is handled internally, this unfortunately isn't generally possible today. Some key combinations, like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + non-alphabetic cannot be mapped, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + letter vs. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + letter cannot be distinguished. (Unless your terminal sends a distinct *termcap* code for it, which most don't.) In insert or command-line mode, try typing the key combination. If nothing happens / is inserted, you cannot use that key combination. This also applies to `<Tab>` / `<C-I>`, `<CR>` / `<C-M>` / `<Esc>` / `<C-[>` etc. (Only exception is `<BS>` / `<C-H>`.) This is a known pain point, and the subject of various discussions on vim_dev and the #vim IRC channel.

Some people (foremost Paul LeoNerd Evans) want to fix that (even for console Vim in terminals that support this), and have floated various proposals, cp. http://groups.google.com/group/vim_dev/browse_thread/thread/626e83fa4588b32a/bfbcb22f37a8a1f8

But as of today, no patches or volunteers have yet come forward, though many have expressed a desire to have this in a future Vim 8 major release.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I guess I'll just have to get used to using ctrl-w for vim and ctrl-backspace for browsers.

Comment: The good thing about Ctrl-W is that it also works in Bash etc.

Comment: Yeah, I know. But you still have to use ctrl-backspace for everything else, and the fact that ctrl-w seems to be standard for closing tabs and windows everywhere else makes it annoying. I'll probably get used to it after a while though.

Comment: But can this be solved purely in the vim code base? How any code in the vim code base distinguish between backspace and ctrl+backspace if the terminal it is running in sends vim the same exact input for either key combination? Seems like this is something that must be fixed in the terminal that vim is running in, not vim. For example, Guake sends `^?` for both backspace and ctrl+backspace, which makes them (AFAIK) indistinguishable. xterm, on the other hand, sends `^H` for backspace and `^?` for ctrl+backspace, making them distinguishable.

Comment: But unfortunately, in xterm, backspace (`^H`) is indistinguishable from ctrl+h (`^H`). Perhaps we can create a new escape sequence to be able to distinguish all three? I don't know how easy that is, but it seems like it'd be safe to do because with the current state of things (some terminals use `^?` for backspace, others `^H`, and vice versa) I can't imagine very many terminal apps (if any at all) consider the ctrl+backspace scenario (it'd be completely indeterministic due to the variety of terminals)...

Comment: (cont'd.) and thus adding some new escape sequence wouldn't really break much, if anything at all. It'd only add a way to distinguish ctrl+backspace for everyone!